# Display rows in given sequence SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to display rows in given sequence.

I have a table that has parent-child relation in itself. Table looks like this:

```
| ID1(Id)  | ID2(ParentID)| Date  
| -------- | -------- |--------
| 1        | 2        |06/21/13
| 2        | NULL     |06/21/13
| 3        | 2        |06/20/13
| 4        | 5        |06/28/13
| 6        | NULL     |06/07/13
| 5        | NULL     |06/09/13
...
```

There is relation between ID1 and ID2 where parent is ID2 and child is ID1. Parent has its parent always NULL and there may exist Parent that is not linked to anything like ID1. I want to display rows like so:

```
|  Col 1   |  Col 2   | Date
|          |    2     |06/21/13
|    1     |    2     |06/21/13
|    3     |    2     |06/20/13
|          |    5     |06/09/13
|    4     |    5     |06/28/13
|          |    6     |06/07/13
```

So first I need to have displayed Parent and then if there is something linked to Parent then in next rows childer needs to be displayed. All of this needs to be ordered by date. I know how to order by date but I have trouble thinking of solution to displaying correct order of Parent-Child.

EDIT. Order by date in descending order

Comment: Why the row with ID2 not in the output? And if the parent is the ID2 column how is the row where ID2 = NULL even valid? How can you have a child row with no parent? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I does make sense and that is how it works. There might be a scenario when parent doesnt have child not the other way round.

Comment: The calling them a parent/child is probably the wrong terminology. In the data world that doesn't work.

Comment: This is how the out of the box table works and I don't think your comment has anything to do with my question

Comment: It does as I am trying to understand your objective.

Comment: Where is row ``| 4        | 5        |06/28/13`` in desirable output?

Comment: Please update your question with a complete and consistent example. Show the expected `Date` values in the results. Make `ID2` value `5` make sense. Aside: Typically when representing a hierarchy there are rows that have an `Id` and `ParentId`. That allows for multiple children of a single parent and arbitrary depth. Having a `ChildId` and `ParentId` in a row is perplexing because that leaves the row without an `Id`, just relations to other rows that lack `Id` values. Searching for [`[tsql] sort hierarchy`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btsql%5D+sort+hierarchy) might be helpful.

Comment: OK updated answer with the new requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand how date is relevant here since it is not part of your output. But this will return the rows you stated you want in the order you want them.

--EDIT--

Your sample data and desired output changed. Here is the new version.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID1 int
    , ID2 int
    , [Date] date
)
insert @Something values
(1, 2, '06/21/13')
, (2, NULL, '06/21/13')
, (3, 2, '06/20/13')
, (4, 5, '06/28/13')
, (6, NULL, '06/07/13')
, (5, NULL, '06/09/13')

select s2.ID1
    , s2.ID2
    , s.Date
from @Something s
join @Something s2 on s2.ID2 = s.ID1

union all

select s.ID2 --yes ID1 and ID2 are reveresed on purpose here because what was in the first column in needed in the second column
    , s.ID1
    , s.Date
from @Something s
where s.ID2 is null
order by [Date] desc
    , ID2
    , ID1
```